# Calculating min, max, mean, and standard deviation of a large array doesn't return any output

Tags: multidimensional-array, fortran, mean, gfortran, standard-deviation

I am struggling to calculate the mean, standard deviation, and find the min and max values of a large array in Fortran. There are no errors in my code below, but I am not receiving any values in my output file. Therefore, I believe my code to calculate the mean, standard deviation, and obtain the min and max values is incorrect.

Background - I first calculated Red NDVI and Green NDVI, which are 2 types of a Normalized Difference Vegetation Indices (NDVI). I calculated the RNDVI and the GNDVI for where seagrass was present in a large AscII file imported from ArcGIS. Now, I am trying to find the minimum and maximum RNDVI and GNDVI. And I am also trying to calculate the mean and standard deviation of these large text files that consists of the different Vegetation Indices (VIs).

```
PROGRAM Seagrass
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER, DIMENSION (2) :: Location, Location1, Location2, Location3, Location4
REAL, DIMENSION (:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: RNDVI, GNDVI, Seag, Green, Red, Infrared!, n, i
INTEGER :: NCOL, NROW, CELL, NoData, ROW, COL
REAL :: XCORD, YCORD, m1, s1, m2, s2
CHARACTER (LEN=14) :: TEMP

!Read in necessary files
OPEN(1, FILE = "D:\Fall_2021\Advance_Environmental_Modeling\Lab_6\seag_ascii.txt", status="old") !Read
OPEN(2, FILE = "D:\Fall_2021\Advance_Environmental_Modeling\Lab_6\red_ascii.txt", status="old") !Read
OPEN(3, FILE = "D:\Fall_2021\Advance_Environmental_Modeling\Lab_6\infrared_ascii.txt", status="old") !Read
OPEN(4, FILE = "D:\Fall_2021\Advance_Environmental_Modeling\Lab_6\green_ascii.txt", status="old") !Read
OPEN(5, file= "D:\Fall_2021\Advance_Environmental_Modeling\Lab_6\Seagrass\RNDVI.txt", status="Unknown")!Write
OPEN(6, file= "D:\Fall_2021\Advance_Environmental_Modeling\Lab_6\Seagrass\GNDVI.txt", status="Unknown")!Write


!Read in Header of files
READ (1, *) TEMP, NCOL
READ (1, *) TEMP, NROW
READ (1, *) TEMP, XCORD
READ (1, *) TEMP, YCORD
READ (1, *) TEMP, CELL
READ (1, *) TEMP, NoData

READ (2, *) TEMP, NCOL
READ (2, *) TEMP, NROW
READ (2, *) TEMP, XCORD
READ (2, *) TEMP, YCORD
READ (2, *) TEMP, CELL
READ (2, *) TEMP, NoData

READ (3, *) TEMP, NCOL
READ (3, *) TEMP, NROW
READ (3, *) TEMP, XCORD
READ (3, *) TEMP, YCORD
READ (3, *) TEMP, CELL
READ (3, *) TEMP, NoData

READ (4, *) TEMP, NCOL
READ (4, *) TEMP, NROW
READ (4, *) TEMP, XCORD
READ (4, *) TEMP, YCORD
READ (4, *) TEMP, CELL
READ (4, *) TEMP, NoData

!Allocation of Variables
ALLOCATE (Seag(NROW, NCOL))
ALLOCATE (Green(NROW, NCOL))
ALLOCATE (Red(NROW, NCOL))
ALLOCATE (Infrared(NROW, NCOL))
ALLOCATE (RNDVI(NROW, NCOL))
ALLOCATE (GNDVI(NROW, NCOL))

!Do loop of readingin files
DO Row= 1, Nrow
READ(1,*)(Seag(Row, Col), Col=1, Ncol)
READ(2,*)(Red(Row, Col), Col=1, Ncol)
READ(3,*)(Infrared(Row, Col), Col=1, Ncol)
READ(4,*)(Green(Row, Col), Col=1, Ncol)
END DO

! Loop Calculating NDVIs in Datasets
DO ROW =1 , NROW
DO COL = 1, NCOL
IF (Seag(Row, Col)==1) THEN
RNDVI(ROW,COL) = ((Infrared(ROW,COL)-Red(ROW,COL))*1.0/(Infrared(ROW,COL)+Red(ROW,COL)))
GNDVI(ROW,COL) = ((Infrared(ROW,COL)-Green(ROW,COL))*1.0/(Infrared(ROW,COL)+Green(ROW,COL)))
END IF
END DO
END DO

!Writing NDVIs to files
WRITE(5,*)RNDVI
WRITE(6,*)GNDVI

!Reading in NDVI Files
DO Row= 1, Nrow
READ(5,*)(RNDVI(Row, Col), Col=1, Ncol)
READ(6,*)(GNDVI(Row, Col), Col=1, Ncol)
END DO

m1= 0.0
m2=0.0

DO ROW =1 , NROW
DO COL = 1, NCOL
IF (RNDVI(Row, Col)/=1) THEN
m1 = sum(RNDVI)*1.0/(max(1, size(RNDVI))
!m1 = sum(RNDVI, RNDVI /=0)/(max(1,count(RNDVI /=0)))
s1 = sqrt(sum(RNDVI**2 )/size(RNDVI) - m1**2 )
END IF
END DO
END DO

DO ROW =1 , NROW
DO COL = 1, NCOL
IF (GNDVI(Row, Col)/=1) THEN
m2 = sum(GNDVI)/size(GNDVI)
s2 = sqrt(sum(GNDVI**2 )/size(GNDVI) - m2**2 )
END IF
END DO
END DO

WRITE(*,*)m1
WRITE(*,*)s1

WRITE(*,*)m2
WRITE(*,*)s2

! Min & Max Values
location1 = maxloc(RNDVI, Mask =(Seag == 1))
location2 = minloc(RNDVI, Mask =(Seag == 1))

location3 = maxloc(GNDVI, Mask =(Seag == 1))
location4 = minloc(GNDVI, Mask =(Seag == 1))


! Print out the subscripts and correponding NDVI value
WRITE (*, *) location1, RNDVI(location(1),location(2))
WRITE (*, *) location2, RNDVI(location(1),location(2))

WRITE (*, *) location3, GNDVI(location(1),location(2))
WRITE (*, *) location4, GNDVI(location(1),location(2))

STOP


END PROGRAM Seagrass
```

Why am I not getting any output values?

Comment: Welcome. You did not ask a  question. What is your question? Is there any problem with the code you posted? Any error messages? Or wrong results? What does your code print? Is it correct or incorrect? See [ask].

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this. I'm not getting any error messages. The output just won't print out the mean, standard deviation, min, and max. So, after I read in the NDVI output files, I cant seem to obtain the mean, standard deviation, min, and max value. I think the code regarding these values is incorrect and I need help with correcting and printing out this specific code.

Comment: Be aware that opening external files at unit numbers less than 10 is risky. Opening 5 and 6 in particular is playing with fire, they are very often used for standard input and output. If there is no output on the screen, the reason might be there. Use some larger unit numbers.

Comment: I think the question/problem they're trying to ask is "Why am I not receiving any values in my output file?" (based on the writing but yea the question doesn't seem clear)